# Media Queries are not working on Blogspot

Tags: css, blogspot

I am trying to implement media queries on blogspot here - http://cricketbeta.blogspot.in/

But they are not working, please give it a look and tell me where I am wrong

```
    @media screen and (max-width : 479px) {
/* If screen size less than 479px Load these styles */
/* Done for Smart Phones */
.content{width: 100%!important;}
.sidebar{display: none;}
.container{width:100%;
#topmenu{display: none}
}


@media screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width : 768px) {
/* If screen size less than 768px Load these styles */
/* Done for Tablets */
#middle .content{width: 100%!important;}
.sidebar{display: none;}
.container{width:100%;}
.header-bottom{width:100%}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
/* If screen size less than 960px Load these styles */
/* Done for Tablets */
.content{width: 100%!important;}
.sidebar{width: 100%;}
.container{width:100%;}
.header-bottom{width:100%}
}
```

Comment: what's the supposed behaviour ? I see some rules are used when I resize my window, so it works

Comment: Your media queries are working perfect

Answer (score 0):

The media queries I use are below. It looks like you might be missing a few of the specifiers.

iPhone:

> @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px)
>   and (max-device-width: 480px) and (max-device-height: 480px) and
>   (orientation:portrait) {
>
> }
>
> @media only screen and (max-device-width:
>   480px) and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 480px)
>   and (orientation:landscape) {
>
> }

iPad:

> @media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px)
>   and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and
>   (orientation:portrait) {
>
> }
>
> @media only screen and (max-device-width:
>   1024px) and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-height: 1024px)
>   and (orientation:landscape) {
>
> }

Comment: I want to hide sidebar and make content width 100% in all devices with width less than 1040px.

Comment: Well then inside the right media query add display: none and width: 100% to the divs you want to affect. We're here to help, not do your work for you!